# Reactjs, this.context is undfined in constructor method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, fluxible

i m actually trying to develop a simple component corresponding to a list that I fill with one more item when I hit a button.

My problem is that I use ES6, and so I dont use getInitialState, I use the constructor to make the initialization, like explained in the doc.

My problem is that now, this.context is undefined in my constructor, and I cant get my first time array (or the pre-loaded array) directly inside of the consntructor :

```
import React from 'react';
import ListStore from '../stores/ListStore';

class Client extends React.Component {


  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getStoreState(); // throw me that in getStoreState, this.context is undefined
  }


  static contextTypes = {
      executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      this.context.getStore(ListStore).addChangeListener(this._onStoreChange.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.context.getStore(ListStore).removeChangeListener(this._onStoreChange.bind(this));
  }

  _onStoreChange () {
     this.setState(this.getStoreState());
 }

  getStoreState() {
      return {
          myListView: this.context.getStore(ListStore).getItems() // gives undefined
      }
  }


  add(e){
    this.context.executeAction(function (actionContext, payload, done) {
        actionContext.dispatch('ADD_ITEM', {name:'toto', time:new Date().getTime()});
    });
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <h2>Client</h2>
              <p>List of all the clients</p>
              <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
              <ul>
                  {this.state.myListView.map(function(test) {
                    return <li key={test.time}>{test.name}</li>;
                  })}
              </ul>
          </div>
      );
  }
}


export default Client;
```

I just want to pre-load the array in the constructor even if its empty or not, and that's exactly what my store returns :

import BaseStore from 'fluxible/addons/BaseStore';

```
class ListStore extends BaseStore {

  constructor(dispatcher) {
      super(dispatcher);
      this.listOfClient = [];
    }

  dehydrate() {
      return {
          listOfClient: this.listOfClient
      };
  }

  rehydrate(state) {
      this.listOfClient = state.listOfClient;
  }


  addItem(item){
    this.listOfClient.push(item);
    this.emitChange();
  }

  getItems(){
    return this.listOfClient;
  }

}

ListStore.storeName = 'ListStore';
ListStore.handlers = {
    'ADD_ITEM': 'addItem'
};

export default ListStore;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `this.context` supposed to be?

Comment: It's the Fluxible context from the tool that I use : https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/master/docs/api/Components.md

Comment: Already try to bind the current context, and it doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because your component should be stateless,
I can't say this enough, state should live in your stores, (UI-state, "could" live in your components but thats debatable)

What you should do is use a higher level component, wrap your react component within a higher level component, let that component fetch the state from the store, and pass it as props to your component.

This way you don't need initial state, you can just set your defaultProps, and propTypes.

This way your component is stateless, and you could make complete use of the react lifecycle, it also become reusable, because you don't have the logic of fetching the actual data within your component.

#### Good reads

- props vs state: https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md)
- higher level components: http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/05/02/react/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If the component (children in your case) is stateless, this means that I use props, and then I cant just refresh the data with the state, am I right ? How should I do ?

Comment: no when u do setstate it would do as it says, it will set the state, of itself, and it will trigger are rerender, it will also rerender all child components within this component - but this is not the case, you receive the new properties from your higher level components, so when your higher level component receives data from ur store or wherever it gets it from u should pass them to the component it wraps and it will (refresh is not the right word, it will Re-render) automatically. Then u can hookup within the livecycle shouldcomponentupdate ,or willreceiveprops ..etc (and do something there)

Comment: i was looking at fluxable http://fluxible.io/addons/BaseStore.html <-- it has a change listener, u could make i donno what fluxible has for events, but u could make your higher component listen for changes on your store, so it automaticly passes the props on "change"

the eventlistener is build in, so when it changes, use the callback to call ur function, that passes the props, and voila ur component is updated 

- i didnt work with fluxable but took a quick look at there docs.